# block split in malloc

Tags: c, split, malloc

Im writing my own implementation of malloc and I am having a bit of trouble with the "split" part. I know I have to implement it in this part of the code.

```
        struct s_block *last = linked_list;
        block = find_free_block(&last, size);
        if (!block) // FAILED TO FIND A FREE BLOCK
        {
            block = try_to_fusion(last, size);
            if (!block)
            {
                return NULL;
            }            
        }
        else // FREE BLOCK WAS FOUND
        {
            block->free = 0; //NEED TO SPLIT BLOCK HERE
        } 
    }
    return(block+1);
}
```

Comment: What does the computer need to do to split a block?

Comment: @user253751 I am not sure I understand what you mean. I need to add a split function to my code to "cut" the the block and create a new block with the rest of the size.

Comment: And what does this actually mean? What is cutting a block?

Comment: @user253751 Basically, some blocks are going to have a bigger size then what I need. For example, I might need 2 bytes and the available block has a size of 4 bytes. I need to "cut" the block to only use the 2 bytes necessary for optimization and not taking unnecessary space.

Comment: Yes, and what does this actually mean? What is a block and what does it mean to cut one? For example, somehow the computer has to remember that the first block is only 2 bytes, not 4, right? Or does it? I'm asking you so that you will think about it.

Comment: @user253751, omg. Idk what happened but I GOT IT. No idea what you did, but thanks a lot!!

Comment: my point is to make you think about what the computer has to do. There are no blocks in the computer. There's only memory. You invented the blocks yourself. And (I presume) you know how to read and write memory and make calculations. So you have to figure out: what reading and writing and calculating does splitting a block entail? Then you tell the computer to do the reading and writing and calculating.